# Track GA4 custom event

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am sending a custom event ("ebook") with a parameter ("titolo") to  GA4. After that, I have set the parameter as a Custom Dimension in GA UI.

I am sending the event from my website with this code:

```
function ebooksGA4new(title) {
    gtag('event', 'ebooks', {
        'titolo': title
    });
}
```

Then I have set an Exploration on the custom dimension, but after 3 days it still reports "not_set. If I fire the event, I can see it in the real-time report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to find out why

1. Modify the code a bit, make sure it won't trigger the event if it doesn't have title parameter.

But please `make sure this is what you want`. You need to decide it is ok or not to receive the event without title parameter.

```js
function ebooksGA4new(title) {
    if(!title || title=="")
      return false;
    gtag('event', 'ebooks', {
        'titolo': title
    });
}
```

2. Open the chrome devtool or something similar with it. Here is the screenshot about how to check it. This should appear on your GA4 real time report as well.

[image]