# How to send specific information from client side to Google Analytic 4 (NOT Universal)?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

While defining tag and triggers in [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/), is there a way I could define that specific information from my client goes into `GA4`? for example I want to send the so-called `store code` whenever a user click on a button, so that I can understand exactly which store has had this click. The click event is not my point, I have already defined the tag and trigger, my problem is that why in the response `GA4` gives me some info is missing.

in my Tag I have defined a new event with  the parameter shown in photo:

[image]

then the trigger is

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you already set the parameter?

Comment: the parameter I want is not predefined there. I have a variable named `storeCode` from my back-end which would be unique for every web-page of every store

Comment: Can you share about how you set up the GA4 tag? Then I can share about the corresponding way to add the parameter

Comment: I edit my question so that I can share screenshots. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way to send info, based on this link [[GA4] Custom events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events?client_type=gtag) which is a JavaScript code. However this is not what I was searching for because it is dependent to coding part and I wanted something which I can do from GTM

```
<script>
  /**
  * The following event is sent when the page loads. You could
  * wrap the event in a function to call the event when certain
  * events (e.g., a click event) happen on your site.
  */
  gtag('event', 'Your Event Name', {
    'your_param1': 'value 1',
    'your_param2': 'value 2',
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify the parameter name like this

[image]

If this setting is not working. Then the problem will be the `{{Click Text}}` is not returning as you expected.

Comment: even the store_code parameter is not showing in the parameter list. and click text is not going to contain the store code because that variable is receiving its value from a json file imported. I have this kind of variables since my page is dynamic.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about store_code is not showing in the parameter list? You mean the GA4 report? It’s a custom parameter you need to configure it in your GA4. Here is the document link https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en

Comment: store_code is my custom parameter that I defined it. I do not have anything to write in the value input box. you proposed {{Click Text}}, but this is not the value I want to send.

Comment: I used the same method in the link you sent, as you can see in the below code part. This method my problem is how to read from Java these values sent by gtag. Since they are not embedded in GA4.

Comment: OK got it. Now our only problem is how to fetch the `store_code` from you website. Can you share the html or screenshot about where is the `store_code` on your webiste?

Comment: I have some information including store code, imported or included from various method into my page. for this case, simply it is a variable which is inserted into a file by back end, next in front end I have included that file, so if I write a php echo for every variable inserted in that file I have the access to the value.
<script>
  gtag('event', 'btnClick', {
    'store_code': '<?php echo $code; ?>',
  });
</script>

Comment: I can say I have the same problem as well which is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73485834/track-ga4-custom-event
Is it possible that after 48 hours I can see the results? because if I need to solve the problem either from coding part or from GTM